# Next.js domain routing with sub-domains

Tags: reactjs, routes, localization, internationalization, next.js

I am trying to translate my Next app based on the current sub-domain. For example, I would like `en.hello.com` to be in English, and `it.hello.com` to be in Italian.

I am trying to achieve that using Next's [domain routing](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/i18n-routing#domain-routing), but apparently, that is not meant to be used with sub-domains but rather with top-level domains like `hello.en` and `hello.it` for English and Italian for example.

Here is my **next.config.js**:

```
module.exports = {
  i18n: {
    locales: ["en", "it"],
    defaultLocale: "en",

    domains: [
      {
        domain: "en.hello.com",
        defaultLocale: "en",
      },
      {
        domain: "it.hello.com",
        defaultLocale: "it",
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

These settings fail to map `en.hello.com` to English and `it.hello.com` to Italian.

**Can anybody explain why that is and how can I achieve sub-domain routing in Next?**

Answer (score 2):

What you're trying to do does not seem to be a supported feature. Per your own provided [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/i18n-routing#domain-routing), you can have either a top level locale domain such as `.it` or a sub-path such as `/it`. Now i'm not sure why you want a subdomain when majority of websites on the internet are opting for the sub-path. If you choose sub-path, then by providing the `Accept-Language: it;q=0.9` header user will be redirected automatically.

**Alternative**

If you're unable to utilize either of supported features, then your only other option is to create [custom servers](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-server). This comes with a lot more work and you'll also lose the ability to deploy to vercel platform.